# How can I call ggsave without producing any output like `Saving 7 x 7 in image`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to suppress the `Saving 7 x 7 in image` output of `ggsave()` whenever I run it, but it seems impossible. Is this possible? How to do it?

I have tried the following, but nothing works:

- `capture.output()`
- `sink()`
- changing the warnings option
- assign it to a variable

Minimal ``working'' example:

```
librrary(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
                      y = rnorm(30))
plot.to.be.saved <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = gp, y = y))
sink('/dev/null')
ggsave(filename = '~/.so.pdf', plot = plot.to.be.saved)
sink()
# Saving 7 x 7 in image

options(warn=-1)

no.output.please <- ggsave(filename = '~/.so.pdf', plot = plot.to.be.saved)
# Saving 7 x 7 in image
capture.output(ggsave(filename = '~/.so.pdf', plot = plot.to.be.saved), file = 'NUL')
# Saving 7 x 7 in image
```

Comment: I filed https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4847.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ggplot2:::plot_dim` issues this as a message, so `suppressMessages(ggsave("test.pdf", ggplot()))` should do.

Answer (score 13):

If you get a message like:

> Saving 6.45 x 7.47 in image

`ggsave()` is telling you how large it rendered the image because no size values were specified.

Add the following to `ggsave()` to prevent this message:

```
width=w, height=h
```